# Difference between "Upscale", "high-toned/tony", "fancy", "high-end", "select", and "exclusive"

Tags: vocabulary, word-usage

Can these terms denoting something expensive, elegant and/or fashionable be used just about interchangeably, or are there any subtle differences to them?

E.g.

> Alone in a tony restaurant...[source](http://www.newyorker.com/arts/reviews/film/how_do_you_know_brooks)
>
> In a high toned restaurant...[source](https://www.thewinesociety.com/resources/feature_images/latest-news/society-news-pdf/past-editions/downloads/jan_11.pdf)
>
> People have to be taught how to behave or dress in a fancy restaurant.[source](http://www.businessinsider.com/how-to-act-at-a-fine-restaurant-2013-10)
>
> The novel's claustrophobic premise is the gathering of two couples for dinner in a high end restaurant.[source](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/03/10/books/review/the-dinner-by-herman-koch.html?pagewanted=all&_r=0)
>
> We had a leisurely dinner in an exclusive restaurant...[source](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=1qPnYFOtQC8C&pg=PA61&lpg=PA61&dq=%22in+an+exclusive+restaurant%22&source=bl&ots=xAmBI_vnb6&sig=b-leZEyDyEgGCt8Vy6if40WTApI&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=JEQTU7aVDoiW0QX6hoDICg&ved=0CEwQ6AEwCDhG#v=onepage&q=%22in%20an%20exclusive%20restaurant%22&f=false)
>
> One could assume they were in an upscale restaurant...[source](http://www.reviewjournal.com/view/southwest/sparklings-offer-upscale-casual-dining)
>
> Dinner at a select restaurant...[source](http://www.glennbond.com/whistler-daily-itinerary/)>/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first four examples and upscale have a roughly identical meaning, which is expensive and of high quality, being typically patronized by the wealthy and notable. (Admittedly I had to look up tony, because it's not common in AmE.)

The remaining, *exclusive* means something slightly different.

Exclusive implies that it is difficult to get a reservation due to a degree of discrimination on the part of the management.   Usually this is due to the extreme popularity of the restaurant, leading to a situation where the remaining tables can only be gotten by people who are of some sort of elite status (celebrities, wealthy, etc.). This is a ploy by the management to make their restaurant seem more desirable by dint of their famous clientele.

Comment: "Tony" is pointed up as an Americanism in various of my bilingual dictionaries out here, and reportedly originates from "high-toned".

Comment: I'm sure it is real.  I've just never seen it used outside that New Yorker article.  We (in my social circle that does patronize this type of establishment) usually say high-end or upscale. *Fancy* is usually used by people who don't patronize that type of place as often.

Comment: I also thought that "exclusive" denoted the expensive prices found in that sort of restaurants rather than the clientele.

Comment: @NourishedGourmet That is another take on it, that the prices are selecting the clientele.  But, that would imply that anyone who has enough cash can waltz in and get a table. That is rarely the case.

Comment: None of those examples are much used in Britain - certainly not "tony" or "high-toned". We might speak of a "smart restaurant", a "good-quality restaurant", an "up-market" restaurant, or (informally) a "posh restaurant". The word "fancy" has quite a different meaning in Britain - as does "smart".