# What is a "tony shop"?

Tags: meaning, foreign-phrases, transliteration

This appears to be an uncommon phrase. Google returns nothing. Perhaps it's a foreign transliteration. Here is the excerpt:

> The notice posted on Thursday said the embassy had received “information of possible threats against Westerners” patronizing the area around Sanlitun, the site of a number of **tony shops** and restaurants.

Source: [U.S. Issues Security Alert for Westerners in Beijing](http://www.wsj.com/articles/u-s-warns-of-possible-threats-to-westerners-in-beijing-1450971612):  from The Wall Street Journal.

Thank you.

Comment: Yep, it means "stylish" and "expensive".  (And Googling "define tony" got me straight to a meaningful definition.)

Comment: @ddodsworthii This might help: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155011/difference-between-upscale-high-toned-tony-fancy-high-end-select

Comment: Thank you. A little foolish of me not thinking tony was not a word on its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It refers to expensive shops.

[Tony](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tony):

> - stylish and expensive:
>
>   - *He ​lives in a tony ​neighborhood of Los Angeles.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

[Tony](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/tony_1):

> - *fashionable and expensive*. (North American English, informal, becoming old-fashioned)

(OLD)

> - The Sanlitun area, to the northeast of central Beijing, is home to many embassies, diplomats and international organizations. ***The area has many bars and restaurants, and its upscale shopping plaza,***  which houses many major international brands, is popular with foreigners and local shoppers alike.

(www.ibtimes.com)

Answer (score 1):

[Apparently](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tony), it means 'stylish or classy', derived from *tone*.  It never really caught on, but one of E.C. Bentley's clerihews reads

> Few Romans were as tony as/ The elegant Petronius./ None who dressed snappier/Appeared on the Via Appia.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "never really caught on".  It's a well-recognized word, just not one that we peons use every day.